# Cos, Sin, Tan or another?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have this circle, and I want to find the lengths of the two green lines. Heres the situation:
[image]

How do I calculate that?

Comment: What you've got there is the unit circle.  The $x$-coordinate of the blue dot is $\cos 30^{\circ}$ and the $y$-coordinate is $\sin 30^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the vertical line's length is $1\times \sin 30$ and the horizontal line's length is $1\times \cos 30$ (in degrees).

Comment: Thank you.
Could you please tell me the formula behind Cos, Sin and Tan.
Also how to use Tan.

Comment: $\cos \phi = x / r$, $\sin \phi = y/r$ , $\tan \phi = y/x$.